# Complex number calculation for exp/log function differs much between MSVC and G++

Tags: visual-c++, g++, precision, complex-numbers

For a conversion of some coordinates to a GPS format I am using complex numbers (std::complex). The algorithm has to be compilable by MSVC (2015) and g++ (7.3.0).

I got a high deviation in the calculation for g++, which is probably much more than the normal floating point precision, while on MSVC it is correct. The deviation is more than 0.04.

For MSVC, it does not matter, if I take low or high precision (/fp:fast or /fp:precise). For g++, I tried also "-ffloat-store" and disabling SSE(2), but it did not help.
Also tried the MPC library (http://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/home.html), but leads to the same result.

For g++, the current flags are

-m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -fno-rtti -fopenmp -g -std=gnu++1y

```
std::complex<double> val = std::complex<double>(-1.8425031517782417e-07, -0.0);
std::complex<double> testExp = std::pow(val, 0.5);
std::cout << "textExp: " << std::setprecision(30) << testExp << std::endl;
```

On MSVC, I got the expected output of (2.628360765983583e-20, **0.0004292438877582582**) , but on g++ I get actual (2.628360765983583e-20, **-0.0004292438877582582**).

So, the imaginary part is not correct for gcc.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks loke a branch cut problem - the imag parts have the opposite signs (but exactly the same magnitudes.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, on second thought, `arg = (-1.8425031517782417e-07, -0.0)` is below the cut so should have a negative imaginary part. `arg = (-1.8425031517782417e-07, 0.0)` is above the cut.

/*
g++ -o so_complex so_complex.cpp
./so_complex
*/

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int
main()
{
  const auto w = std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(w);

  std::complex<double> val = std::complex<double>(-1.8425031517782417e-07, -0.0);
  std::complex<double> testExp = std::pow(val, 0.5);
  std::cout << '\n';
  std::cout << "arg      : " << val << '\n';
  std::cout << "testExp  : " << testExp << '\n';
  std::cout << "testExp2 : " << testExp * testExp << '\n';
  std::complex<double> testSqrt = std::sqrt(val);
  std::cout << "testSqrt : " << testSqrt << '\n';
  std::cout << "testSqrt2: " << testSqrt * testSqrt << '\n';

  std::cout << '\n';
  std::complex<double> valp = std::conj(val);
  std::complex<double> testExpp = std::pow(valp, 0.5);
  std::cout << "argp     : " << valp << '\n';
  std::cout << "testExp  : " << testExpp << '\n';
  std::cout << "testExp2 : " << testExpp * testExpp << '\n';
  std::complex<double> testSqrtp = std::sqrt(valp);
  std::cout << "testSqrt : " << testSqrtp << '\n';
  std::cout << "testSqrt2: " << testSqrtp * testSqrtp << '\n';
}
```

Gives:

```
arg      : (-1.8425031517782417e-07,-0)
testExp  : (2.6283607659835831e-20,-0.00042924388775825818)
testExp2 : (-1.8425031517782414e-07,-2.2564155872441333e-23)
testSqrt : (0,-0.00042924388775825818)
testSqrt2: (-1.8425031517782414e-07,-0)

argp     : (-1.8425031517782417e-07,0)
testExp  : (2.6283607659835831e-20,0.00042924388775825818)
testExp2 : (-1.8425031517782414e-07,2.2564155872441333e-23)
testSqrt : (0,0.00042924388775825818)
testSqrt2: (-1.8425031517782414e-07,0)
```

So MSVC is ignoring signed zero.
libstdc++ is right.